# Running with discrete graphics in Kubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

Hello I am using the latest version of Kubuntu 22.04.2 on my Acer Nitro laptop and I was wondering if there is a "Run with Discrete Graphics" option in the desktop environment like in Ubuntu where you right-click this and run with the dedicated gpu on the laptop from the menu? I don't see this option anywhere and the only way I know that works is to use the command line method to do this. Any other ways to get this on the menu like in regular Ubuntu? Thanks.